# How to change the view-name referred to by the default Django reset-your-password email template?

Tags: python, django

This is the default reset-your-password email template in Django 1.7:

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

In my `urls.py` the `password_reset_confirm` view uses this alternate name: `password_reset_3of4_new_password_form`.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
#Passing keyword arguments through url entries:
# - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^login/$", "auth_lifecycle.registration.views.login_maybe_remember",
        name="login"),
    url(r"^logout_then_login/$", "django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login",
        {"login_url": "login"}, name="logout_then_login"),
    url(r"^password_reset_1of4_email_request/$",
        "django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset",
        { "template_name": "registration/password_reset_1of4_email_request.html",
          "post_reset_redirect": "password_reset_2of4_email_sent" },
        name="password_reset_1of4_email_request"),
    url(r"^password_reset_2of4_email_sent/$",
        "django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done",
        { "template_name": "registration/password_reset_2of4_email_sent.html" },
        name="password_reset_2of4_email_sent"),
    url(r"^pwd_reset_3of4_new_pwd_form/(?P<uidb64>\w+)/(?P<token>[\w-]+)/$",
        "django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm",
        name="password_reset_3of4_new_password_form"),                         #<--HERE
    url(r"^password_reset_4of4_finished/$",
        "django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete",
        name="password_reset_4of4_finished"),
)
```

Is there any way to change the view-name used by the default email template? I don't see any relevant parameter in the [`password_reset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) view. I'd like to avoid manually duplicating and then editing this template (which would then be referred to by the `email_template_name` parameter).

Comment: Why change the name at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Because the names of the four password_reset views are confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view name in the template is a string literal, not a variable, so you can't override it without changing the template.

If you specify a different template using the `email_template_name` argument, then you can extend the original template, and override the specific block that you want to change.

```
{% extends "registration/password_reset_email.html" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_3of4_new_password_form' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
```

Personally, I think that changing the view names in this way will be confusing to any other Django developers who are used to the original names.

Comment: Between you and @DanielRoseman, I am now convinced not to change the names. I'm writing [a tutorial](https://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/django_auth_tutorial_7/) on how to implement the reset-your-password feature (as a tool to teach myself), and I don't want to teach something that's unacceptable to established Django programmers.

Comment: It's also interesting to see how template inheritance can be used to extend an existing template, as opposed to how they're normally used in the tutorials I've gone through, where the main templates in your site extend a "base.html"

Comment: If you're writing a tutorial, then I think you've made a good decision to stick with the existing names, and explain what each view does.

Comment: There isn't a general purpose `base.html` template that comes with Django, so most of the time you have to create it yourself. Note that you can only override the specific block because you could specify the template name. If you had overridden the template by creating another "registration/password_reset_email.html" in your templates directory, there isn't anyway to extend the 'original' "registration/password_reset_email.html" template.

Comment: Right, "base.html" is common practice (and the name normally used), not anything built in.